# Want to change SQL query to LINQ

Tags: linq

I want to change the below simple SQL query into LINQ , how do I change it ?

```
select * from table1 where isPaid = 'true' and  Id in (select Id from table2 where EmployeeId = 12)
```

similar to this ?

```
from pa in db.PaymentAdvices
where pa.IsPaid == true
orderby pa.PaidDate descending
select pa;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here code linq to sql:

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
where t2.EmployeeId = 12
select t1
```

Hope usefull!

Comment: thanks, but  i have edited my question, can you please recheck it ?

Comment: Its returning different records than the SQL query records.

Answer (score 0):

if the field **isPaid** has datatype is **Boolean**:

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
where t2.EmployeeId = 12 and t1.isPaid == true
select t1
```

if the field **isPaid** has datatype is **String**:

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
where t2.EmployeeId = 12 and t1.isPaid.Equals("true")
select t1
```